# Does turning me to super user get me access to all applications sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

I am building a game for android and I want to put the `game score` in the `SharedPreferences` of the application.

I was wondering if a user has rooted his phone, and made him super-user, will he be able to get my `SharedPreferences` file and change it?

Comment: If a user has *rotted* their phone, they're not getting *any* files any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Once a user has `su`, they can access any file on the file system from the adb shell.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  So how can i keep my high score safe?

Comment: Keep it in sharedprefs and encode them with simple hash if you think that is necessary, the highscore and the preferences filename, think of social engineering. Not everyone has rooted phone and not everyone will come up with idea of changing a highscore, having the fact in hand that not everyone knows what is shared preferences, speaking of regular phone users.